# How do I read a string in XML then display an error message in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am still learning c# and have an question.  I have an XML file that I need to query to see if the application I am needing to access is down or not.  The XML file has all the connection information for the app.  If it's down I need to display a message on screen that tells the user it's down.

I am having a bit of confusion as to how I would write this.  I want it to check first thing so I will be putting it first thing under Page_Load.  Any help is appreciated.

This is what i've written but obviously it has its problems

```
var loanconnect = new LoanRouterService(Settings.getString("Vendors/WebApp/LoanRouterURL"));
        if (loanconnect == null || loanconnect == string.Empty)
        {
            appResponse.Text = "<p>Test message deal with it.</p>";
        }
```

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far. You should include your XML file. These two things will make your question much easier to answer.

Comment: This has been answered before -- see Related links on this page. Search 1st. Try code 2nd. When that doesn't work, post your relevant code and related errors as question.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  New to the site so I didn't see that stuff.

Comment: Do you have a problem with: reading the XML file, connecting to the application specified in the file, displaying a message on the screen? What did you try to overcome those problems?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have something that runs on a timer in your Global.asax file that downloads and parses your xml file. This way you won't need to do it on every page hit. Either store that value in a global static property off the application class or in cache.

Then from your page, in Page_Load, read the value and write the html to display it.